# python dir search using re and os

Tags: python, path, pipeline, nuke

Im trying to create a dir search using re argument.
When a location have been search through a want sort it in a list to be used as a pulldown menu. For a user to access the information and choose (i guess this is software bound in my case nuke.Panel)

When the user have picked it should enter phase 2 of searching within the chosen directory.

Issue I'm having is that it seems that i don't get it back as something i can look through, like a list to see what was picked up and give me the option to choose one and continue

```
import nukescripts
import nuke
import re
import os
from glob import glob


## Based on folder structure : sequence/sq010(sqXXX)/sh120(shXXX)/comp(cleanup, key, roto)

os.environ['sequence'] = '/Volumes/postergren/Projects/TD/assetmanagerTest/sequence'
os.environ['SEQ'] = ''
os.environ['SHOT'] = ''
os.environ['DEP'] = ''

# Check to see if ENV set already
env_check = os.environ.get('sequence')

myPanel = nuke.Panel("Asset Manager - Setup")
myPanel.setWidth(350)


## SEQ FOLDER
seqPath = os.path.join(os.getenv('sequence'))
seqPathDirs = [os.path.join(seqPath, dir) for dir in os.listdir(seqPath) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(seqPath, dir))]
seqPattern = re.compile('sq(\d+)')

for i in seqPathDirs:
    thisDir = os.path.split(i)[1]
    if seqPattern.match(thisDir):
        os.environ['SEQ'] = (i)
        # Panel
        myPanel.addEnumerationPulldown("Sequence: ", os.environ['SEQ'])
    if myPanel.show():
        os.environ['SEQ'] = myPanel.value("Sequence: ")

nuke.tprint(os.environ['SEQ'])


## SHOT FOLDER
shotPath = os.path.join(os.getenv('sequence') + os.getenv('SEQ'))
shotPathDirs = [os.path.join(seqPath, dir) for dir in os.listdir(seqPath) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(seqPath, dir))]
shotPattern = re.compile('sh(\d+)')

for i in shotPathDirs:
    thisDir = os.path.split(i)[1]
    if seqPattern.match(thisDir):
        os.environ['SHOT'] = (i)
        # Panel
        myPanel.addEnumerationPulldown("Shot: ", os.environ['SHOT'][:])
    if myPanel.show():
        os.environ['SHOT'] = myPanel.value("Shot: ")
## END SHOT FOLDER


nuke.tprint(os.environ['SHOT'])
```